# How can you use a variable name inside a Python format specifier

Tags: python, formatting

Is it possible to use a variable inside of a Python string formatting specifier?

I have tried:

```
display_width = 50
print('\n{:^display_width}'.format('some text here'))
```

but get a `ValueError: Invalid format specifier`.  I have also tried `display_width = str(50)`

however, just entering `print('\n{:^50}'.format('some text here'))` works just fine.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes, but you have to pass them in as arguments to `format`, and then refer to them wrapped in `{}` like you would the argument name itself:

```
print('\n{:^{display_width}}'.format('some text here', display_width=display_width))
```

Or shorter but a little less explicit:

```
print('\n{:^{}}'.format('some text here', display_width))
```

Since this question was originally posted, Python 3.6 has added f-strings, which allow you to do this without using the `format` method and it uses variables which are in scope rather than having to pass in the named variables as keyword arguments:

```
display_width = 50
text = 'some text here'
print(f'\n{text:^{display_width}}')
```

Comment: Yep, that's it!  I actually used your second option, but added identifiers to make it a little more explicit: `print('\n{0:^{1}}'.format('some text here', display_width))`.  This allowed me to be a little more creative like in a for loop: `print(('{0:>{2}} : {1:<}').format(k, v, width_adj))` where `width_adj = display_width//2 - 2`.

Comment: @ChristopherPearson Yep, that looks like a pretty reasonable way to do it.

Comment: As a note https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/ mentions `^` is for centering, `>` is for right aligned, and `<` is for left aligned

Comment: is there a way to do that using the 3.6 formatted string idiom `f"..."`?

Comment: The first option did not work for me in  3.6.1 but the second version (variable as an arg to format) works fine. Is this expected behavior for 3.6?

Comment: @Omortis the first option works fine for me in Python 3.6. `display_width = 50; print('\n{:^{display_width}}'.format('some text here', display_width=display_width))`. Can you show the code that doesn't work for you?

Comment: @steffen The answer is yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60838497/5693642

Comment: @steffen have updated my answer to include f-strings

Answer (score 2):

Python f-string is more flexible.

```
>>> display_width = 50
>>> display_content = "some text here"
>>> print(f'\n{display_content:^{display_width}}')

                  some text here
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
print(('{0:^'+str(display_width)+'}').format('hello'))
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems like since this question was first posted, python introduced f-strings. See [this web page](https://cito.github.io/blog/f-strings/) for info.

```
>>> name = 'Fred'
>>> age = 42
>>> f'He said his name is {name} and he is {age} years old.'
He said his name is Fred and he is 42 years old.
```