# python print format, read indentation value from a variable

Tags: python, printing, format

```
print('{:>85} '.format("PASS"))
```

This is working fine,
I want to read that 85 from a variable

```
indent = 85
print('{:>indent} '.format("PASS"))
```

Comment: Also [How can you use a variable name inside a Python format specifier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29044940/15497888)

Comment: You should be using f-strings by the way, they have advantages over `str.format()`.