# Formating python string with constants?

Tags: python

I'm using python formating to print some left aligned columns.

This nicely left alignes `a`, `b` and `c`:

`out_string = '{:30} {:20} {:10}'.format(a, b, c)`

Then I tried using constants, but failed with `ValueError: Invalid format specifier`:

```
ALIGNa = 30
ALIGNb = 20
ALIGNc = 10
out_string = '{:ALIGNa} {:ALIGNb} {:ALIGNc}'.format(a, b, c)
```

Why does it fail?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use an f-string?

Comment: You can find the explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29044940/how-can-you-use-a-variable-name-inside-a-python-format-specifier).

Try formatting with fstring-

```out_string = f'{a[:ALIGNa]} {b[:ALIGNb]} {c[:ALIGNc]}'```